# bypass validation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

this is the first time i've used Validation with jQuery and my code to validate a dropdown is:

```
jQuery(dropdown).validate({
    expression: "if (VAL != '-1') return true; else return false;"
});
```

this works ofcourse when i want my 'dropdown' to be validated.

ISSUE: I'm adding a class = "ignore" to dropdown when i don't want it to be validated, is there a way to bypass the validation when my dropdown has a class "ignore"?

I've tried to add IGNORE but i don't know if it's the right way,(obviously it isn't because it's not working):

```
jQuery(dropdown).validate({
    expression: "if (VAL != '-1') return true; else return false;",
    ignore: ".ignore"
});
```

this is the code i've tried. please help mo on this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add a check before and return true when the class is ignore for the dropdown.

```
if ($(dropdown).attr('class') == "ignore")
    return true;
```

Do this check before doing anything else.

Comment: thanks for the response @AurA.. hmmm, actually i've also tried doing that before the line of codes i've written above<br/>but for instance, the dropdown was validated the first time which is ok, but on 2nd validation, even if i have the checking of the dropdown class, it was still validated, i don't know but it seems that the validation is already bound to the dropdown control